# Laravel custom attribute not being mutated to Carbon date

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, laravel-5.6

I'm having problems getting Laravel to cast a custom attribute as a `Carbon` date. Here's an example model:

```
class Organisation extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        'my_date'
    ];

    public function getMyDateAttribute() 
    {
        return "2018-01-01 00:00:00";
    }
}
```

I'd expect `my_date` to be cast to a `Carbon` date however if I do `dd($organisation->my_date)` it just returns the date as a string.

I've seen people suggest to just return a `Carbon` instance from the custom attribute, and this partially works, the `my_date` attribute is availabe as a `Carbon` instance within the application, however if you then return the model as Json you end up with:

```
{
    "name": "Big Business",
    "my_date": {
        "date": "2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/London"
    }
}
```

Instead of the desired:

```
{
    "name": "Big Business",
    "my_date": "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
}
```

Has anyone else come across this and if so have you found a solution?

---

### Update

Upon further investigation I've tracked down the problem (but I don't have a solution yet). When you return an Eloquent model the `__toString` magic method which runs the `toJson` method and as you trace down the chain it serializes any Carbon dates in the `$dates` variable. It also completely skips over this serialization for mutated attributes, which is what I'm seeing.

I need to find a way to seralize mutated attributes that return a `Carbon` date when `__toString` is called.

Comment: I believe the accessor overrides the `protected casts` and `protected dates` attributes. What's the desired behaviour for you?

Comment: You want the date as a `Carbon` instance in your application and as a simple string in the JSON response?

Comment: ^ This actually happens if you just add the field to `protected $dates`. I think the asker is confused by the representation with different dumping methods.

Comment: devk: Yes it does appear that the accessor overrides the protected casts and dates. Basically I want a custom attribute that behaves the same way as, for example, the `created_at` date.

Jonas: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

edit your `Organization` model to this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
class Organisation extends Model
{


    public function getMyDateAttribute($value) 
    {
        //you can manipulate the date here:
        $date = Carbon::parse($value,config('timezone'));
        return $date;
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly, this is just example of what you can do with the carbon instance there, in this case converted to unix timestamp

Comment: if you explain to me what you want to do with the instance i can edit it

Comment: I want a custom attribute to behave the same way as, for example, a `created_at` attribute in terms of being cast to a Carbon instance within the code but appearing as a string in Json.

Comment: and btw this is for custom date columns in migration of organizations, for the default timestamps they are already instance of carbon

Answer (score 0):

You if your model represents a table, you can change the data type to timestamp and laravel will put that attribute into a carbon object.

Once the attribute is a carbon object, you can change the format in the blade view.

```
{{ $organisation->mydate->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

If either cannot change the data type, or you need to a default format different from a timestamp you can use the 'cast' eloquent model property.

```
class Organisation extends Model{

     protected $cast = [
         'mydate'=>'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s'
     ];

 }
```

Casting the attribute effectively works the same as an accessor that wraps the date value with a carbon object.  This is much cleaner way to write it, however.

As far as timezone is concerned, you should look to change that in the config/app.php file.

Here is the documentation....  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting